# Creating a Transaction Controller Leads to Unexpected Error

Tags: php, joomla, authorize.net

I'm currently developing an extension for one of my Joomla websites to integrate with Authorize.net. I followed the 'Hello World' example from their site to derive the following sandbox source code:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; 
use net\authorize\api\contract\v1 as AnetAPI;
use net\authorize\api\controller as AnetController;

define("AUTHORIZENET_LOG_FILE", "phplog");

...

// Common setup for API credentials  
$merchantAuthentication = new AnetAPI\MerchantAuthenticationType();   
$merchantAuthentication->setName("<redacted: login id>");   
$merchantAuthentication->setTransactionKey("<redacted: transaction key>");   
$refId = 'ref' . time();

// Create the payment data for a credit card
$creditCard = new AnetAPI\CreditCardType();
$creditCard->setCardNumber("4111111111111111");  
$creditCard->setExpirationDate("2038-12");
$paymentOne = new AnetAPI\PaymentType();
$paymentOne->setCreditCard($creditCard);

// Create a transaction
$transactionRequestType = new AnetAPI\TransactionRequestType();
$transactionRequestType->setTransactionType("authCaptureTransaction");   
$transactionRequestType->setAmount(151.51);
$transactionRequestType->setPayment($paymentOne);
$request = new AnetAPI\CreateTransactionRequest();
$request->setMerchantAuthentication($merchantAuthentication);
$request->setRefId($refId);
$request->setTransactionRequest($transactionRequestType);

// Error on the following line:
$controller = new AnetController\CreateTransactionController($request);

$response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse(net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::SANDBOX);   

if ($response != null) {
    $tresponse = $response->getTransactionResponse();
    if (($tresponse != null) && ($tresponse->getResponseCode() == "1")) {
        echo "Charge Credit Card AUTH CODE : " . $tresponse->getAuthCode() . "\n";
        echo "Charge Credit Card TRANS ID  : " . $tresponse->getTransId() . "\n";
    } else {
        echo "Charge Credit Card ERROR :  Invalid response\n";
    }
} else {
  echo  "Charge Credit Card Null response returned";
}
```

I'm getting an error stating `syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)`. I couldn't find anything wrong with the line the error happened on so in trying to debug the error I traced it back to `net\authorize\api\controller\base\ApiOperationBase` whose constructor generates this error at several points. That doesn't seem right to me, especially when considering one of the offending lines is simply:

```
$this->logger = LogFactory::getLog(get_class($this));
```

And so now I'm lost, because I'm not sure what else I can debug in a Hello World sandbox transaction. I installed authorize.net using composer, and I'm running this with PHP v7.0.32 on Joomla! v3.9.1 Stable. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: For reference, the constructor of `AnetController\CreateTransactionController` looks like this:

```
public function __construct(AnetApiRequestType $request)
{
    $responseType = 'net\authorize\api\contract\v1\CreateTransactionResponse';
    parent::__construct($request, $responseType);
}
```

and the parent constructor (`ApiOperationBase`) looks like this, with the three lines that each independently cause the same error noted:

```
public function __construct(\net\authorize\api\contract\v1\AnetApiRequestType $request, $responseType)
{
    // Error on the line below (syntax error: '?')
    $this->logger = LogFactory::getLog(get_class($this));

    if ( null == $request)
    {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException( "request cannot be null");
    }

    if ( null == $responseType || '' == $responseType)
    {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException( "responseType cannot be null or empty");
    }

    if ( null != $this->apiResponse)
    {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException( "response has to be null");
    }

    $this->apiRequest = $request;
    $this->validate();

    $this->apiResponseType = $responseType;

    // Error on the line below (syntax error: '?')
    $this->httpClient = new HttpClient;

    // Error on the line below (syntax error: '?')
    $serializerBuilder = SerializerBuilder::create();

    $serializerBuilder->addMetadataDir( __DIR__ . '/../../yml/v1', 'net\authorize\api\contract\v1');//..\..\yml\v1\ //'/../lib/net/authorize/api/yml/v1'
    $serializerBuilder->configureHandlers(
        function (HandlerRegistryInterface $h)

        use($serializerBuilder)
        {
            $serializerBuilder->addDefaultHandlers();
            $h->registerSubscribingHandler(new BaseTypesHandler()); // XMLSchema List handling
            $h->registerSubscribingHandler(new XmlSchemaDateHandler()); // XMLSchema date handling
        }
    );
    $this->serializer = $serializerBuilder->build();
}
```

As commented by Alex Howansky, there aren't any question marks in the source code apart from the regular  tags. It's very confusing for me.

Comment: There is no question mark in the code you posted. Post the lines around the point where the error is showing.

Comment: @AlexHowansky, Thanks for replying! The absence of question marks anywhere near the bugged code is super confusing for me as well. Nevertheless, I added the constructors of the classes as I got nearer to the source of the error and commented the three points that they occurred in the API's source code.

Comment: _"generates this error at several points"_ Syntax errors are fatal, you can't get more than one. Please post the entire text of the error. Also run `php -l <file>` on each of your files, that will highlight individual syntax errors in each, without having to run the app.

Comment: I found the error at several points because when I commented out a line that caused the syntax error, the syntax error would reappear at another line. I'm aware that this may cause other errors as well but the exact same syntax error appeared on each of those lines when the others were removed.

Comment: Ah ok, then you likely have an unterminated ternary somewhere. Do the `php -l` thing and you should be able to find which file it's in.

Comment: `php -l` reports no syntax errors, so it's possible that this is a weird Joomla bug maybe?

Comment: Post the entire text of the error.

Comment: Joomla only reports [this](https://prnt.sc/m47j3l) as an error page. I can't get it to show a stack trace for some reason (which is why I resorted to commenting things out to find out where the error occurred).

Comment: You'll need to get the full text of the error from your web server's error log.

Comment: I put the code in an isolated php script and ran it, successfully! So I realized that my version of PHP on the web server v7.0.32 was incompatible with what I was trying to do, apparently, but switching to PHP v7.3.0 on the website made it work. What a weird problem. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Please read the comments on the question for detail about getting to this solution.

It turns out that the PHP version (7.0.32) was causing problems with the version of Authorize.net I was using (1.9.9). Updating PHP to 7.3.0 fixed the error.

Comment: In the future please post your Joomla questions on Joomla Stack Exchange so that other Joomla researchers can easily find your discovery.  When the system allows it, please "accept" your answer.

Comment: @mickmackusa I can't accept it for a little while but I've been planning on it! And thank you, I didn't know about the Joomla SE and I'll note it for the future.